# My do/while loop messes my program up the second time around

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while, palindrome

The issue I am having is once I input a word like "non" I get back it IS a palindrome. I then type "Yes" as I ask "Keep Going?". It starts back up at "Type Word:" and I type "non" again. This time however I get back it is NOT a palindrome. I think it has something to do with how I declare my variables or possibly with the for loop. I can't figure it out though. Any Help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class palindromeTest
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  String word = "", backword = "", exit = "";
  int length;
  do{
     System.out.print ("Type a Word: ");
     word = in.nextLine();

     length = word.length();

     for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        backword = backword + word.charAt(i);
     if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(backword))
        System.out.println ("This IS a Palindrome.");
     else 
        System.out.println ("This is Not a Palindrome.");

     System.out.println ("Keep Going? /n Yes or No?");
     exit = in.nextLine();
  }while(exit.equalsIgnoreCase ("Yes"));
}//end main
}//end palindromeTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of `backward` into the loop body (so it resets on each iteration),

```
String word = "", exit = "";
int length;
do {
    String backword = "";
```

However, it's a better idea to use `StringBuilder` for `String` concatenation but I'll leave optimization as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That was it. I always have trouble in remembering where to place declarations when using do/while loops. Thank You